# Clicking dates in a calendar with python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, calendar

I am having a tough time figuring out how to click the start and stop date in a calendar with Python and Selenium. Below is the HTML code for the calendar and a screenshot of what it looks like. In the calendar you select the start date first and then the end date and it highlights everything in between.

[image]

```
<td class="day ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="day in week" ng-class="{
        'now':isNow(day),
        'active':isSameDay(day),
        'disabled':(day.getMonth()!=date.getMonth() || isDayDisabled(day)),
        'after':isAfter(day),
        'before':isBefore(day)
      }" ng-click="setDate(day)" ng-bind="day.getDate()">6</td>

<th colspan="5" class="switch ng-binding" ng-click="setView('month')">2020 July</th>

<p class="cndrTitle ng-binding">Start Date</p>

<th colspan="5" class="switch ng-binding" ng-click="setView('month')">2020 July</th>
```

Comment: can you add proper html ? pasting your code and html as a image is not a good practice its quite difficult to debug and find accurate solution.

Comment: i did sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void setcalender(String monthyear2, String date2,String monthyear3, String date3) {
        // driver.findElement(By.id("xpath of month  year")).click();

       

        while (true) {
            String CurrentMonth = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of title]")).getText();
            if (CurrentMonth.equals(monthyear2)) {
                break;
            } else {

// click next arrow option until get user input 
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).click();
            }
        }
       
        driver.findElement(By.linkText(date2)).click();
            }

    //click on thru date title
        driver.findElement(By.id("xpath")).click();
        

        while (true) {
            String CurrentMonth = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your xpath]")).getText();
            if (CurrentMonth.equals(monthyear3)) {
                break;
            } else {
// click next arrow until get date
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath)).click();
            }
        }
        
        driver.findElement(By.linkText(date3)).click();
       
    
    }
```

Comment: can you share you url for calendar so that I can go through much more

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtveSBQHvWE. follow this link it will help you

Comment: I can’t share the URL this is not a public site and I am using Python not JAVA

Comment: Programming language is not matter when you do automation , try my approach in python